# Using multiple IF function to based on two columns and bring TRUE or FALSE in the third column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a large amount of data. After using `Match` `Index` formula I get a small amount of data then filter them to get the sheet like attached picture in below.

[image: picture 1]

Column C is showing if the road is wet or dry and column D showing rainfall in millimeter. I want to say if road is wet and rainfall is >0 the result is TRUE or if road is Dry and rainfall is =0 the result is TRUE, otherwise result is FALSE. 
I am trying to use formula like below but it is not working.

```
=IF(D27=0,AND(C27="Dry",TRUE,IF(D27>0,AND(C27="Wet",TRUE),FALSE)))
```

I want the result be like this:

[image: result picture]

Comment: I want the result be like this:

Answer (score 1):

`IF(OR(AND(D27=0,C27="Dry"), AND(D27>0, C27="Wet")), TRUE, FALSE)`